# Cannot run with sound null safety because dependencies don't support null safety

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I have followed ["Enabling null safety" on `dart.dev`](https://dart.dev/null-safety#enable-null-safety) and also [**migrated**](https://dart.dev/null-safety/migration-guide) my whole Flutter application to null safety.

Now, I am trying to run it using `flutter run`. However, it will not start because of the following error:

```
Error: Cannot run with sound null safety, because the following dependencies
don't support null safety:

 - package:cloud_firestore_web
 - package:firebase_core_web
 - package:shared_preferences
 - package:url_launcher_web
 - package:firebase_auth
 - package:http
 - package:provider
...

For solutions, see https://dart.dev/go/unsound-null-safety
Failed to compile application.
```

The guide at the URL says that I should ["wait for dependencies to migrate before you migrate your package"](https://dart.dev/go/unsound-null-safety), but I want to use [non-nullable by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60068435/what-is-null-safety-in-dart) (NNBD) now.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 348, accepted):

First, you should read through the guide to [understand unsound null safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/unsound-null-safety). If you are sure that you want to run your application with unsound null safety, you can use the following command:

```
flutter run --no-sound-null-safety
```

The `--no-sound-null-safety` option is not documented in the article, however, I have not experienced any problems with it for the last few months (and especially not since the whole Flutter framework has been migrated to null safety).

The documentation has now been updated to include this. See [Testing or running mixed-version programs](https://dart.dev/null-safety/unsound-null-safety#testing-or-running-mixed-version-programs).

#### IDE run arguments/configuration

To set this up in your IDE of choice, you can use:

- In **IntelliJ**/**Android Studio**: "Edit Configurations" (in your **run** configurations) → "Additional run args".
- In **Visual Studio Code**: search for "Flutter run additional args" in your user settings.

In both cases, add `--no-sound-null-safety`.

#### Test configuration

For tests, you will want to do the same thing:

- In **IntelliJ**/**Android Studio**: "Edit Configurations" (in your **run** configurations) → "Additional args".
- In **Visual Studio Code**: search for "Flutter test additional args" in your user settings.

In both cases, add `--no-sound-null-safety`.

Comment: @ChiragArora you can add it to the additional arguments in your run configuration (click on the dropdown where it says `main.dart` next to the device and then on "Edit configurations").

Comment: it it possible add fastlane build with `no-sound-null-safety` parameter? @creativecreatorormaybenot

Comment: not works in flutter 2.2.x when build a ios package @creativecreatorormaybenot  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67914266/seems-no-sound-null-safety-parameter-not-work-in-flutter-2-2-1

Comment: Saved my life with the VSCode tip - also setting Flutter test additional args (note "test"!!) - that makes the unit tests work. Thanks!

Answer (score 155):

**In Android Studio:**

Run → *Edit Configurations* → *Add Additional Run args* → *--no-sound-null-safety*

[image]

Comment: in flutter 2.2.x when build ios it works? @issac https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67914266/seems-no-sound-null-safety-parameter-not-work-in-flutter-2-2-1

Comment: This didn't work " dC:\src\flutter\flutter\flutter>flutter run --no-sound-null-safety
Downloading Web SDK...                                            120.8s
Error: No pubspec.yaml file found.
This command should be run from the root of your Flutter project." but a  configuration worked : Run --> Edit Configurations --> Add Additional Run args --> --no-sound-null-safety

Answer (score 59):

***Easy Solution***

If you are using [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code), then go to:

- Menu *File* → *Preferences* → *Settings*
- Search for **"Flutter run additional args"**
- Then click <kbd>Add Item</kbd>
- Now type `--no-sound-null-safety`
- Click <kbd>OK</kbd>.

Answer (score 55):

You run into this error if your code is not fully migrated to null-safety. You can run your "mixed-version" code:

- **Using the [Android Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Studio) IDE**

  *Copy:* `--no-sound-null-safety`

  [image]

  [image]
- **In the Dart file**

  Add `// @dart=2.9` at the top in your `main.dart` file and run the app using the Play ► icon.

  ```dart
  // @dart=2.9
  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

  void main() {
    //...
  }
  ```
- **Using the command line**

  ```
  flutter run --no-sound-null-safety
  ```

  Or to be specific (say in [Chrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome))

  ```
  flutter run -d chrome --no-sound-null-safety
  ```

Answer (score 50):

If using Visual Studio Code, create file *.vscode/launch.json* in the project root and add:

```
"args": [
         "--no-sound-null-safety"
        ]
```

Complete code:

```
{
        // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
        // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
        // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
        "version": "0.2.0",
        "configurations": [
                {
                        "name": "YOUR_PROJECT_NAME",
                        "program": "lib/main.dart",
                        "request": "launch",
                        "type": "dart",
                        "args": [
                                "--no-sound-null-safety"
                            ]
                }
        ]
}
```

Answer (score 18):

In case you were using **Visual Studio Code** and faced it in your **unit test**.

Visual Studio Code → *Preferences* → *Settings* → *Search setting, type in "flutter test"* → *Dart: Flutter Test Additional Args, Add item* → *Add "**--no-sound-null-safety**"*

[image: --no-sound-null-safety description picture]

Comment: That would be a correct answer if it was for Flutter Test. But if you are getting an error while running that you should add the Additional Args for Flutter Run. so search for Flutter Run in Settings. and then add like above one.

Answer (score 9):

If you want run your project with `--no-sound-null-safety`, you can add this line to your `main.dart` file at the top (first line) with a comment...

`// @dart=2.9`

Then your project runs with `--no-sound-null-safety`...

Comment: In  my case, I have added " // @dart=2.9"; however, in TEST\main.dart

Answer (score 8):

Run

```
dart pub outdated --mode=null-safety
```

in a terminal and if there is a development dependency update then update the dependency.

That might help.

Answer (score 7):

The problem happens because the Flutter framework (version 2.2.0 and up) is now supporting sound null safety out of the box, but there are plenty of package and plugins on *pub.dev* are not migrated to null safety yet, so that's raising the error whenever you run a `build` or `run` command.

To overcome this issue, add the flag `--no-sound-null-safety` in your command.

Example:

```
flutter build [Target] --no-sound-null-safety
```

Target arguments:

For Android:

```
"apk" or "appbundle"
```

For iOS:

```
"ipa"
```

Comment: a more example, this work for me:
flutter build apk --release --no-sound-null-safety

Answer (score 6):

1. Execute the following command in the terminal to accept all SDK package licenses

   ```
   flutter doctor --android-licenses
   ```
2. Run the following command in the terminal to check if there are any platform dependencies to complete the set up:

   ```
   flutter doctor
   ```

   **OUTPUT:**

   Doctor summary (to see all details, run `flutter doctor -v`):

   [√] Flutter (Channel dev, 2.2.0-10.1.pre, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.928], locale en-US)

   [√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)

   [√] Chrome - develop for the web

   [√] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)

   [√] Visual Studio Code (version 1.55.2)

   [√] Connected device (3 available)

   • No issues found!
3. If *no* issues are found then execute the following command to build an application with unsound null safety

   ```
   flutter run --no-sound-null-safety
   ```

Answer (score 3):

Adding to [creativecreatorormaybenot's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64917744/cannot-run-with-sound-null-safety-because-dependencies-dont-support-null-safety/64917745#64917745):

If you're building your [APK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APK_%28file_format%29) file or [AAB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_App_Bundle) file without sound null safety:

**Just do this on your terminal**

```
flutter build apk --split-per-abi --no-sound-null-safety
```

or

```
flutter build apk --release --no-sound-null-safety
```

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal → use this command → `flutter run -d chrome --no-sound-null-safety`.

This should work.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose, in case, anyone gets this error for `flutter_html: ^0.8.2`.

Add the following to your *pubspec.yaml* file:

```
dependencies:
  flutter_html: ^3.0.0-alpha.2
```

So, it is proved that using any dependency in the project must be the latest version which includes null-safety mechanism.

So, before using `"--no-sound-null-safety"` solution, try to search and use the upgraded version of your dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

For visual studio code user, add below to settings.json

```
"dart.flutterRunAdditionalArgs": [
    "--no-sound-null-safety"
],
```

Answer (score 1):

use this one its worked for me

```
  flutter pub upgrade --null-safety
```

Comment: command not supposed now - The `--null-safety` flag is no longer supported.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you all install this package, to maintain the  control over the null values in other implementations:

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_swiper_null_safety/install

Answer (score -1):

Update your library version to the latest. Nowadays most of the library support.

Comment: Re *"Nowadays most of the library support"*: Something seems to be missing. Do you mean *"Nowadays, most of the libraries support it"*? Or something else? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70727651/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).