# Cannot run with sound null safety, because the following dependencies don't support null safety

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub

> /C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/video_player_platform_interface-2.2.0/lib/messages.dart:4:1: Error: A library can't opt out of null safety by default, when using sound null safety.
> // @dart = 2.8
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> /C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/wakelock_platform_interface-0.1.0+1/lib/messages.dart:4:1: Error: A library can't opt out of null safety by default, when using sound null safety.
> // @dart = 2.8
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> Error: Cannot run with sound null safety, because the following dependencies
> don't support null safety:

Hi,

I imported project from other person. When I try pub get it say **requires SDK version >=2.12.0 <3.0.0, version solving failed.** Then i Updated dart it through this error.

Solution 1:

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64917744/cannot-run-with-sound-null-safety-because-dependencies-dont-support-null-safety)

I have tried above link solution still throughs this above error

Answer (score 7):

Try this,
Go to terminal and run this command;
*flutter run --no-sound-null-safety*

Answer (score 2):

Only one line Magic code can Build your APK.

-> open Main file.

-> write this line on the 1st top line.

```
     **" // @dart=2.9 "**
```

->  run apk. or build apk