# Can anyone can tell how to solve this issue as i have tried all existing solutions

Tags: flutter, dart, sdk, apk, flutter-dependencies

[image]

**I have tried all solutions on the internet and everywhere but nothing works so if someone can help me to solve this issue and this issue occurs when i try to make build for my Flutter App project**

this is my yaml file

Comment: Can you please provide your `pubspec.yaml` file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you might be using an old version of the plugin_platform_interface package.

you should have a line like this in your pubspec.yaml file:

```
dependencies:
  plugin_platform_interface: ^2.0.1
```

note that according to the instructions on pub.dev this package only supports null safety in version 2.0 and above.  see more at

[plugin_platform_interface version log](https://pub.dev/packages/plugin_platform_interface/changelog)

Comment: where should i add this in yaml? it says this

Comment: you should already have a line in your YAML file that has "plugin_platform_interface:" in it.  After the ":" you need to make sure the version number that your programme is dependent on is above 2.0.  I can't see your YAML file in your post.

Comment: alternatively you can add the dependency to your YAML file without having to edit it manually by using the following command in terminal:- $ flutter pub add plugin_platform_interface

Comment: don't forget to run "$ flutter pub upgrade" to make sure you get the latest version included in your build.

Answer (score 0):

```
flutter run --no-sound-null-safety
```

Check this:
[Cannot run with sound null safety because dependencies don't support null safety](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64917744/cannot-run-with-sound-null-safety-because-dependencies-dont-support-null-safety)