# Flame 0.29.4 cannot run with sound null safety

Tags: flutter, flame, forge2d

When trying to run my Flame application I get the following error:

> Error: Cannot run with sound null safety, because the following
> dependencies don't support null safety:
>
> - package:flame
> - package:ordered_set
> - package:box2d_flame

I have the following in my `pubspec.yaml` file:

```yaml
dependencies:
  flame: ^0.29.4
  flame_box2d: ^0.0.1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot run with sound null safety because dependencies don't support null safety](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64917744/cannot-run-with-sound-null-safety-because-dependencies-dont-support-null-safety)

Comment: flame and box2d_flame packages not yet updated for Null safety, you should use different package or wait for package developers to update

Comment: Hi, one of the authors of Flame here, just use this in your pubspec file instead (0.26.x doesn't support null safety):
Under your `dependencies:` section add: `flame: 1.0.0-releasecandidate.16` and `flame_forge2d: 0.8.2-releasecandidate.15`.
box2d_flame has been renamed to flame_forge2d.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flame `0.29.4` doesn't support null safety, you can use the latest release candidate of version 1.0.0 if you want null safety (it is more stable than `0.29.4` anyways, and all the docs are for that version).

To use the newest release candidate together with Forge2D, put the following in your `pubspec.yaml` file:

```
dependencies:
  flame: ^1.0.0-releasecandidate.16
  flame_forge2d: ^0.8.2-releasecandidate.15
```

Do note that `box2d_flame` has been renamed to `flame_forge2d`, since the physics engine is now called `Forge2D`.