# "Cannot run with sound null safety" Flutter an existing Project?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I had an existing application which i want to modify, I am using following dependencies:

```
  path_provider: ^2.0.8
  http: ^0.13.4
  html: ^0.15.0
  custom_pop_up_menu: ^1.2.2
  share: ^2.0.4
  connectivity: ^3.0.6
  flutter_swiper: ^1.1.6
```

Following error, i have even created a new empty project and added the dart files to that project but it is not working now.

```
    Error: Cannot run with sound null safety, because the following dependencies
don't support null safety:

 - package:flutter_swiper
 - package:plugin_platform_interface
 - package:flutter_page_indicator
 - package:transformer_page_view
```

Comment: try running with no null safety flag: `flutter run --no-sound-null-safety`
Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64917744/5669120

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot run with sound null safety because dependencies don't support null safety](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64917744/cannot-run-with-sound-null-safety-because-dependencies-dont-support-null-safety)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because some of the `dependencies` that you are using not supports null-safety and to solve this you can  `upgrade` your `dependencies` or use below `command` to run your application without `null-safety`.

```
flutter run --no-sound-null-safety
```

Comment: Downloading Web SDK...                                             21.8s
Downloading CanvasKit...                                            7.6s
Error: No pubspec.yaml file found.
This command should be run from the root of your Flutter project...

Comment: Go to your project folder then run the command

Comment: It works in Edit Config args..

Comment: good to hear that

Answer (score 6):

First upgrade your flutter and  packages upto  date,

1. Run `flutter pub outdated --mode=null-safety` to print all outdated packages.
   Than,
2. Run this, `flutter pub upgrade --null-safety` to upgrade all packages automatically

Comment: Best solution till now

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:
Upgrade your flutter and packages upto date
Run `flutter pub outdated --mode=null-safety` to display all outdated packages. Then, Run `flutter pub upgrade --null-safety` to upgrade all packages with no sound null safety

Option 2:
Run `flutter run --no-sound-null-safety`

Option 3:
If you want to run your applications with no sound null safety,
For VSCode user, add below to settings.json

```
"dart.flutterRunAdditionalArgs": [
    "--no-sound-null-safety"
],
```