# Flutter null safety http, shared_preferences requiring plugin_platform_interface without null safety. How to fix it?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

So, I added two devDependencies in flutter `pubspec.yml`:

```
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.0-nullsafety
  http: ^0.13.0-nullsafety.0
```

Both shared_preferences and http versions are based upon null safety. The flutter application is working perfectly before including these.

But after I try running the app I get the following error:

```
Error: Cannot run with sound null safety, because the following dependencies
don't support null safety:

 - package:plugin_platform_interface

For solutions, see https://dart.dev/go/unsound-null-safety
```

I am not sure which package has a dependency to `plugin_platform_interface`, but how can I solve this without overriding the null-safety rule for code execution?

I don't want to run the code without null-safety.
I didn't include `plugin_platform_interface` anywhere in the dependencies but still getting an error with respect to the same package.

Edit: Moving the dependencies to `dependencies` from `dev_dependencies` doesn't solve the problem. Nor does replacing the versions by `any`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot run with sound null safety because dependencies don't support null safety](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64917744/cannot-run-with-sound-null-safety-because-dependencies-dont-support-null-safety)

Comment: Why are you using such ancient versions of `http` and `shared_preferences`? And why are they under `dev_dependencies` not regular `dependencies`? Change the version to `any` and let the solver do its magic. For example `http: any`. (It's also considered good form to list dependencies alphabetically.)

Comment: Making them `any` I think adds non-null safe dependencies. This was not working

Comment: almost everything is null safe now - you can check at https://pub.dev/packages/http - in the second row you see "null safe"