# Flutter Null Safety issue

Tags: flutter, dart-null-safety

This application is not configured to build on the web.
To add web support to a project, run `flutter create .`.
Launching lib\main.dart on Chrome in debug mode...
Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...
Error: Cannot run with sound null safety, because the following dependencies
don't support null safety:

- package:flutter_speed_dial

For solutions, see https://dart.dev/go/unsound-null-safety
Unhandled exception:

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot run with sound null safety because dependencies don't support null safety](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64917744/cannot-run-with-sound-null-safety-because-dependencies-dont-support-null-safety)

Answer (score 2):

You will need at least version 3.0.0 of that package to have null safety.

Given that they are at version 5.0.0 right now, you should probably update your packages every once in a while.

Comment: how could I upgrade it

Comment: Since you seem to have missed 2 major version changes, you edit the `pubspec.yaml` file to the version you want and then run `flutter pub get`

Answer (score 1):

> Edited:

you will need to latest version and if you want to run without latest version you need to run this command

```
$ flutter run --no-sound-null-safety
```

Comment: thanks but didn't work

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run without latest version you need to Update the Configuration File,

[Edit Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPZFd.png)

Then,

Add `--no-sound-null-safety` in Additional run args.

[Add Command in Additional run args](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjkKT.png)

Then, Click Apply and Run the app.

Comment: Thank you that was awesomly helpful