# Flutter Issue regarding sound null safety because some dependencies doesn't support it

Tags: android, flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6L2o.png)

It is giving the following output:

Launching lib\main.dart on RMX2170 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Error: Cannot run with sound null safety, because the following dependencies
don't support null safety:

- package:http
- package:http_parser

For solutions, see https://dart.dev/go/unsound-null-safety

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1159
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 17s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: use latest version http_parser: ^4.0.2 and http: ^0.13.5

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64917744/cannot-run-with-sound-null-safety-because-dependencies-dont-support-null-safety check the solution here

Comment: In the future, if you could place your code within a codeblock for easier reading, that way others can duplicate your problems easier.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You could check outdated dependencies by

```
dart pub outdated --mode=null-safety
```

For more information check the guide https://dart.dev/null-safety/migration-guide