# Flutter Error when run flutter run --release

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

Error: Cannot run with sound null safety, because the following dependencies
don't support null safety:

- package:path_provider_ex
- package:flutter_file_manager
- package:multi_select_item
- package:flutter_full_pdf_viewer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot run with sound null safety because dependencies don't support null safety](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64917744/cannot-run-with-sound-null-safety-because-dependencies-dont-support-null-safety)

Comment: flutter run works fine i need flutter run --release

Comment: i added no null inside addition argument in main configuration but still getting this error when run flutter --release

Comment: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'D:\sdk\flutter sdk\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1159

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildRelease'.
> Process 'command 'D:\sdk\flutter sdk\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights

Comment: From main.dart configuration set Additional run args to : --no-sound-null-safety in, and from terminal flutter run --release