# error when giving pub get in Android Studio Flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I'm trying to compile a stackfood application, but it's giving this error below, I've already changed fluuter versions, how do I solve it? Do you have any tutorial or step by step?

Resolving dependencies...
The current Dart SDK version is 3.0.0-290.1.beta.

Because universal_ui 0.0.8 doesn't support null safety and no versions of universal_ui match >0.0.8 <0.1.0, universal_ui ^0.0.8 is forbidden.
So, because efood_multivendor depends on universal_ui ^0.0.8, version solving failed.

The lower bound of "sdk: '>=2.7.0 <3.0.0'" must be 2.12.0 or higher to enable null safety.
For details, see https://dart.dev/null-safety

I'm trying to pub get or compile

Comment: The App usually don't work when you remove  null safety, But here is a thread you might find useful! [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64917744/cannot-run-with-sound-null-safety-because-dependencies-dont-support-null-safety]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.