# I receive this error while to run flutter app : Could not find an option named "no-sound-null-safety"

Tags: android, flutter, dart, null

i was developing a flutter app ,my emulator is not working so after trying multiple solutions i decided to unistall the android studio and  install fresh adroid studio ...my emulator is working but my app is not running ...

error....Could not find an option named "no-sound-null-safety".

Run 'flutter -h' (or 'flutter  -h') for available flutter commands and options.

Comment: Can you check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/64917745/5696047

Comment: Make sure you are running your app with "flutter run" command, without any edit configurations in Android Studio