# flutter and dart 3.0.0 upgrade after no-sound-null-safety error

Tags: null

Currently in development, but there is a problem.

After the flutter upgrade today, when I suddenly press debug with the iPhone and Android simulator in android studio, the following comes out, but I have no idea...

---- Message ----

Could not find an option named "no-sound-null-safety".

Run 'flutter -h' (or 'flutter <command> -h') for available flutter commands and options.

-------------------------------------------

However, I looked it up and it says that you can do flutter run --no-sound-null-safety, but it comes out as above...

the questionable part

Run 'flutter -h' (or 'flutter <command> -h') for available flutter commands and options.

This is the part, but I've never seen anything like this come out while compiling...

Does anyone know?

My environment is flutter 3.10.0 and dart 3.0.0.

flutter

- Flutter 3.10.0 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
- Framework • revision 84a1e904f4 (6 days ago) • 2023-05-09 07:41:44 -0700
- Engine • revision d44b5a94c9
- Tools • Dart 3.0.0 • DevTools 2.23.1

dart

- Dart SDK version: 3.0.0 (stable) (Thu May 4 01:11:00 2023 -0700) on "macos_arm64"

Try putting null-safety in Android Studio with --no-sound-null-safety .

Same phenomenon occurs.

Comment: I face the same issues, all of a sudden my code looks like christmas tree,.. errors everywhere after upgrade to flutter 3.10.x

Answer (score 1):

are u using vscode or android studio? if u can run flutter run on terminal, that means that there is `--no-sound-null-safety` specified in either vscode or android studio configuration.. u can fix this by removing that.. for vs code u can check .vscode/launch.json or just open settings and search for "**flutter run additional args**".. for android just edit configuration.. if u can't find it, just search how to enable sound null safety to flutter and from there u know where its specified.

Comment: [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64917744/cannot-run-with-sound-null-safety-because-dependencies-dont-support-null-safety) you can check this link related to no sound null safety

Answer (score -1):

Try with below steps:

Steps 1:

If you are sure that you want to run your application with unsound null safety, you can use the following command:

```
flutter run --no-sound-null-safety
```

Step 2:

If you are using Android Studio

[image]

Step 3 :
If you are VS Code User

[image]

Hope this will help.

Answer (score -1):

**`hi everyone!`** I upgrade my flutter SDK from **3.7.0 to 3.13.0** so also upgrade dart sdk : **3.1.0** then I press the f5 key to debug my project but this error will come:
**Could not find an option named "no-sound-null-safety".**

Run 'flutter -h' (or 'flutter  -h') for available flutter commands and options.

Solution : I am Using VS Code goto settings and find **"Flutter Run Additional Args"** and **remove the --no-sound-null-safety** if you have added before. My Problem Solve You Should try it