# Flutter web app show progress bar with percentage while engine loading

Tags: flutter, loading, splash-screen, flutter-web, progress

I am an Android developer and use [flame engine](https://github.com/flame-engine/flame) to develop a game with flutter for web. Flutter engine loads successfully and game runs well. I show a loading spinner by following steps in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57209754/flutter-web-app-progress-indicator-before-loading-app).
But it shows spinner without percentage. I want to show a progress bar like Unity3d WebGL.

[image: unity show progress bar below the logo]

How can I show the progress bar with correct percentage of flutter engine loading?

Comment: Did you find the solution? if yes, please share.